# How can I use my Canon EOS 20D with Vista x64?

Tags: software, windows, windows-7

It appears that Canon do not offer native 64-bit drivers for any of their range of digital cameras; Is there any way to work around this?

**EDIT** Would I be better upgrading to Windows 7 x64, or no better off?

Comment: For the record, here's the compatibility chart for your camera; note that only EOS Utility is unsupported on 64-bit Vista: http://canoncanada.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/6161

Comment: I don't even use Windows and my EOS 550D was supported right off the bat with Ubuntu 10.10 x64. I can't run the EOS Utility, but there exist much better programs for everything except Windows ;)

Comment: @Blender Canon changed the protocol used over USB after the 20D, and anything since is supported "out of the box" even for remote shooting, etc. across most current operating systems.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This just in:  Microsoft just released [Camera Codec Pack v.16.0.0652.0621](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=26829&utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:%20MicrosoftDownloadCenter%20%28Microsoft%20Download%20Center%29#tm), which is supposed to provide codecs to power Windows Live Photo and Windows Explorer for the following cameras:

- Canon: EOS 1000D (EOS Kiss F in Japan and the EOS Rebel XS in North America), EOS 10D, EOS 1D Mk2, EOS 1D Mk3, EOS 1D Mk4, EOS 1D Mk2 N, EOS 1Ds Mk2, EOS 1Ds Mk3, EOS 20D, EOS 300D (the Kiss Digital in Japan and the Digital Rebel in North America) , EOS 30D, EOS 350D (the Canon EOS Kiss Digital N in Japan and EOS Digital Rebel XT in North America), EOS 400D (the Kiss Digital X in Japan and the Digital Rebel XTi in North America), EOS 40D, EOS 450D (EOS Kiss X2 in Japan and the EOS Rebel XSi in North America), EOS 500D (EOS Kiss X3 in Japan and the EOS Rebel T1i in North America), EOS 550D (EOS Kiss X4 in Japan, and as the EOS Rebel T2i in North America), EOS 50D, EOS 5D, EOS 5D Mk2, EOS 7D, EOS D30, EOS D60, G2, G3, G5, G6, G9, G10, G11, Pro1, S90
- Nikon: D100, D1H, D200, D2H, D2Hs, D2X, D2Xs, D3, D3s, D300, D3000, D300s, D3X, D40, D40x, D50, D5000, D60, D70, D700, D70s, D80, D90, P6000
  Sony: A100, A200, A230, A300, A330, A350, A380, A700, A850, A900, DSC-R1
- Olympus: C7070, C8080, E1, E10, E20, E3, E30, E300, E330, E400, E410, E420, E450, E500, E510, E520, E620, EP1
- Pentax (PEF formats only): K100D, K100D Super, K10D, K110D, K200D, K20D, K7, K-x, *ist D, *ist DL, *ist DS
- Leica: Digilux 3, D-LUX4, M8, M9
- Minolta: DiMage A1, DiMage A2, Maxxum 7D (Dynax 7D in Europe, α-7 Digital in Japan)
- Epson: RD1
- Panasonic: G1, GH1, GF1, LX3

This codec pack should help out quite a bit for Win-64 users.

Comment: D. Lambert swoops in a year later to steal the crown! Nice work!

Answer (score 4):

For image transfers, it should work in PTP mode (or you could use a card reader); you won't be able to remote-control the camera, unfortunately.

To answer your edit, the problem is 64-bit support from Canon for older models, not necessarily the OS itself. However, on Windows 7 Professional, you could possibly run the 32-bit versions of everything in "XP Mode".

Comment: Or, just download VirtualBox (too lazy to link it). It saves you the $200 scam money, and a more versatile (and probably faster) product!

Answer (score 2):

My preference has been to use a card reader. I realize this is not really answering the question, but this is what I've done since the day I got my 20D.

My experience is that transfer speeds are better. I never have compatibility issues. Programs just see the files are being in a normal folder somewhere. Using the Canon software just caused trouble.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, all Canon DSLR's present themselves to the computer as a USB drive.  The drivers for that are built into Windows.  It should work fine with Windows XP, Vista, & 7 in both 32bit & 64bit flavors.

If you're talking about the Canon software that comes bundled with your camera, you can probably download an update from the Canon website.

I installed the Canon software, that came with my 7D, on my x64 Windows 7 system and had no problems at all (although I don't use the software on a regular basis, I know it works).

**EDIT 1**: If you upgrade to Win7 x64, you might be able to use XP mode.  Alternatively, you could install a virtual machine product.  I recommend Sun's [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) because it has the ability to route USB connections to the VM's.

**EDIT 2**: Regardless of how the camera is presented to the computer from a technical perspective ... all the Canon digital cameras I own or have owned have worked fine with all versions of Windows.  Just plug it into the USB and it worked.  Does the 20D require drivers to work on any other version of Windows?

Comment: Canon won't support older cameras on 64-bit platforms, which is why your 7D doesn't have a problem, but his 20D does.

Comment: Does the 20D not present itself as a USB drive?  Windows doesn't care what kind of camera it is, as long as it observes the USB drive protocols.

My 300D (which is older than th 20D, I think), 30D, 40D, and (as I mentioned) 7D all present themselves as USB drives to the computer.

Comment: See this thread on POTN, but short answer seems to be that you need to use PTP mode to perform image transfers, and tethering is completely out of the question (because of no support for EOS Utility): http://photography-on-the.net/forum/showthread.php?t=828948

Comment: @david The 20D does not present itself as mass-storage; in PTP mode it can be used for pulling pictures off, but not for features like remote tethering. There also doesn't appear to be any 64-bit support for viewing RAW files in Explorer (like I'd been doing on 32 bit operating systems on my old laptop before it died)

Comment: None of the Canon DSLRs present themselves as a USB drive. They are, at best, MTP or PTP devices that are represented with a storage-like interface, but the functionality is severely limited compared to a real USB mass storage device.

Comment: OK, I guess I misunderstood the question.

Comment: @david Some things, like the RAW codec [ http://software.canon-europe.com/software/0038095.asp?model= ] just don't work with explorer (or many other applications) on 64bit versions of windows.

Comment: @Rowland yeah, but you were asking about drivers to connect the camera ... and, as far as I know, no drivers are necessary.  At least this is the case with all the Canon DSLR cameras I've had.  Doing special stuff with the camera after it's connected, that's a different story ... and isn't related to drivers.

Comment: @david how would you describe that then? It's not an application, and it's avaialble from the drivers section of the Canon website...

Comment: @Rowland I guess I would simply call it accessory software.  

Driver's are pretty specific (at least related to Windows) ... they control how the OS interfaces with hardware.  In the case of Canon digicams, the drivers are built into the OS.

Comment: David's right ... Driver's control how hardware & the OS interface.  What Rowland's talking about is the accessory software.  There's a significant difference.  Accessory software would work THROUGH the driver.  In the case of a 20D, the *driver* is built into the OS.  The accessory software may or may not support 64bit OS's.  It surprises me that Canon would abandon the 20D in the accessory software though.