# Can I use an EyeFi card to get an immediate display of my shots on my computer screen?

Tags: software, studio

In the past, I've enjoyed practicing studio photography with an immediate display of the just captured image on a computer monitor. I've done this using Canon's capture software for my 20D.

Well, I haven't done this in a while and I've moved to Win7 64 in the mean time. ie no support for Canon's software or the 20D driver (I've always preferred a cardreader for getting my shots)

I was thinking of getting one of the EyeFi pro cards anyway and I'm thinking it may also enable this function.

my Questions:

1. Assuming my wifi is in range of the card, how long after taking a shot does the picture file show up on my computer?
2. Is there a program out there that displays the picture most recently added to a folder?
3. Maybe the EyeFi software already supports this?

Comment: See also: http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/51/21

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might have a hard time making that combination work at all and/or work reliably being as Eye-Fi cards are SD cards, and the Canon 20D takes CF cards. A few people I know have tried to use SD to CF adapters but their results have been mixed, at best. On the Eye-Fi site they say the following about using SD->CF adapters:

"Eye-Fi does not support the use of SD to CF card adapters with the Eye-Fi Card. Eye-Fi has not tested the Eye-Fi Card in cameras designed to use CF cards and has no explicit knowledge to share about the success of these adapters when used with an Eye-Fi Card. We only support the Eye-Fi Card in cameras designed to use SD or SDHC cards.

We are aware that many users want the Eye-Fi Card functionality in their CF-based cameras and have opted to use a CF card adapter to get the functionality offered by an Eye-Fi Card. The following list of known issues with CF card adapters is a collection of information gathered directly from customer and blogger descriptions of issues they have experienced. By sharing this information Eye-Fi accepts no responsibility for problems encountered when using the Eye-Fi Card and a CF Card adapter.

- Wireless range of the Eye-Fi Card is noticeably reduced.
- Formatting the Eye-Fi Card in a CF adapter has caused the Eye-Fi Card to fail.
- File corruption of photos.
- The Eye-Fi Card will not work in Canon 20D, 30D and 40D cameras when used with an “SD/MMC” CF adapter. Use of the newer “SD/SDHC” CF adapters appear to work with the Eye-Fi Card in these cameras."

If you need something more reliable than the 'it might work, but if it doesn't you're on your own' statements from Eye-Fi, and you have a stack of money to burn you can always go the route of buying the Canon WFT-E1 wireless transmitter... It's about as robust as a wireless solution can be, it's an official Canon product, so its supported by Canon, and it's about $900. Ouch.

Now if you're willing to set aside the requirement of 'wireless,' then it's actually relatively easy to get the functionality that you're after, and for a lot less than $900. A simple USB cable to tether your camera to your computer and Adobe Lightroom 3's tethering functionality will give you instant display of any image you take. You can get ~16 feet of play on that USB cable and the setup (assuming you're not already a Lightroom user) will run you about $10 for the cable, and $250 for Lightroom. If you need more than 16 feet you can buy cables with 'signal boosters' built in (such as [this cable](http://www.showmecables.com/viewItem.asp?idProduct=2475&gclid=CKixusvhn6YCFQQPbAod8RNZoA)) which can get you even more distance.

I've used the Canon wireless transmitter setup in a friends studio and his feedback was that the system was great, but expensive and more 'fiddly' than he would have liked. I use the tethered setup I describe on a daily basis in my own studio and it is rock solid, easy to setup and maintain and super convenient. Soooo...

Unless you absolutely need to be able to shoot 30+ feet away from your workstation you'll probably find the tethered solution to be more cost effective and reliable. On the other hand, if you've got a studio space that is large enough that you need to be 30+ feet away from your workstation than probably the $900 for the wireless option isn't that much of a stretch for you anyway... That and the assistant you'll want to hire to keep everything running smoothly. ;-)

Comment: One issue with the USB route is that Canon hasn't released updated drivers for the 20D that work on Win7 64. Thank you for the thorough answer.

Comment: Hmmm... This thread on the Canon Digital Forum (http://photography-on-the.net/forum/showthread.php?t=781794) suggests that with W7 Professional you can use a 'Virtual XP' mode to get around the lack of support. I guess if you're not running W7 Pro you're hosed though.